# Angularjs run an XHR request before each routeChange, regardless of the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a new project, and on the first phase, I would like to check if the user has a session with the server by sending an XHR HEAD request to /api/me.

I would like to use the following syntax

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, current, previous, rejection){/*...*/})
```

The problem is that I don't want to rewrite this code per each controller, is there any way to do this in a generic way?, .run?, service(factory), which way is the correct one?.

please provide a brief smaple of code as I am a total newbie to this framework.

```
var app = angular.module('home', []);
var httpConfig = {withCredentials: true};
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
when('/', 
    {
        template: 'views/home.html', 
        controller: homeCtrl 
    }).
when('/login', 
    {
        template: 'views/login.html', 
        controller: loginCtrl 
    }).
when('/logout', 
    {
        template: 'views/logout.html',
        controller: logoutCtrl

    }).
otherwise(
    {   
        template: 'views/home.html', 
        controller: homeCtrl
    })
}).
run(function($rootScope, authUser){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
        authUser($rootScope);
    })
}).
factory('authUser', function($http, httpConfig){
    var promise = $http.head('/users/me', httpConfig);
})
```

Comment: You can use $routeProvider resolve

Comment: I meant routeChangeStart, not routeChangeError, sorry

Comment: resolve does the same. It would resolve the XHR promise before loading the controller.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have edited my code, can you please advice?

Comment: Try adding resolve:"authUser" inside when() in the $routeProvider definition.

Comment: I am sorry, I am quite new to all of this(let's say a week or so).
What does it mean?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using $routeProvider resolve as below:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
 when('/', 
{
    template: 'views/home.html', 
    controller: homeCtrl,
    resolve:{auth:"authUser"}
}).
when('/login', 
{
    template: 'views/login.html', 
    controller: loginCtrl ,
    resolve:{auth:"authUser"}
}).
when('/logout', 
{
    template: 'views/logout.html',
    controller: logoutCtrl,
    resolve:{auth:"authUser"}

})
```

Also you might need to change your factory function to return the promise:

```
app.factory('authUser', function($http, httpConfig){
    return $http.head('/users/me', httpConfig);
})
```

Comment: authUser should be a factory, should it then return the promise object?

Comment: I suppose that I can delete the:
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
     authUser($rootScope);
 })
lines from the run function, also I need to define a host constant, as I am now using a local REST server, but it will change when moving to stage or prod, where is the best place to do that?

Comment: Also I would like to redirect the user to the login page if the request doesn't resolve(or resolve with an error), is it possible using your solution?

Comment: Yes you can remove the $on. The place where you have defined the routes and other app configs would be a good place to keep the host constant. $route's $routeChangeError method should help with the redirection.

Comment: routeChangeError?, inside of the .run

Excuase me, it's just that I am a little bit confused here

Comment: You can define that in the same way as you have done for routeChangeStart: $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(){}); Though I am not sure if it will help fix the redirection problem.

Comment: It's working fine, thank you very much, the only problem is that the various error codes I get from the API get logged out in the console.

Now I only need to figure out how to design a generic component for an SPA menu in Angular, and a solution fro different roles(say I won't different things displayed in the menu fro the user , admin, and moderator).

I'll publish a new question, and will much appreciate your help :)